# 403 Forbidden Error MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I am using MAMP and MAMP Pro and I am trying to run some php in a new folder. I store the files in the root directory Applications > MAMP > htdocs . When I create a new folder to store a .php folder I get an error message saying

"Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /phptutorial/ on this server."

The folder /phptutorial/ is one I am trying to create I don't understand what seems to be be problem on MAMP since I own and have full rights of the file.

Comment: There's a difference between accessing a folder like `/phptutorial/` and accessing files *within* that folder. In general, if you don't have an index file (e.g., index.php), you can't just request the folder name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [403 Forbidden Error on MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650562/403-forbidden-error-on-mamp)